# When attempting to open an application over X11 forwarding over SSH, why is a local instance of the application opening?

Tags: ssh, x11, users, xforwarding

I'm using SSH to access a jump-box, essentially.

I have two machines. The "local" machine, the one I'm physically seated in front of, is running Fedora 25. The "server" is running Cent OS 7. It sits behind a router, and I use it to hop into the network behind that router. Both machines have an identical user account, "user1."

I connect to the server by opening my favorite terminal emulator on the local machine and entering "ssh -X -p 2201 server-dns.net" where server-dns.net is the correct domain name of the server. I enter my password, and I reach a prompt. When I look at the prompt, I see that my username hasn't changed, but my hostname has.

This is where the confusion begins. Both machines have a copy of Firefox installed, but only the server has a copy of Chromium installed. When I launch Chromium once connected, the remote instance of Chromium appears, and I can browse the remote network. But when I launch Firefox, **my local install of Firefox opens.** Why? When I ssh in as a different user, and launch Firefox, the remote install of Firefox opens. I know this issue is related to the usernames being identical, but how?

Answer (score 3):

Firefox is perhaps too clever for its own good; on the remote system you must specify

```
firefox --no-remote
```

or perhaps instead `--new-instance` to not use the existing local instance.